# Justin is setting a password on his computer. He is told that his password must contain at least 4 but no more than 6 characters.

Tags: probability, statistics

> Justin is setting a password on his computer. He is told that his password must contain at least 4 but no more than 6 characters. He may use either letters or numbers (0–9).
>   How many different possibilities are there for his password if each character can only be used once?
>   Suppose that Justin's computer randomly sets his password using all of the restrictions given above. What is the probability that this password would contain only the letters in his name?

I have some doubt about the second question. I know that the  probability that a randomly chosen password would include only the letters from Justin's name should be found. I think it should be $6!+5!+4!$, while the correct answer is $6!$ and I do not know why. Could anyone explain this?

Comment: The probability is $6!$? That's a serious problem. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

If your password must have at least $4$ characters and $6$ at most, it can either have $4, 5$ or $6$. I am assuming you are using the alphabet *abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz* which has $26$ letters. Adding the numbers $(0, ..., 9)$ you have $36$ possible characters.

Let's calculate separately how many passwords contain $4$, $5$ and $6$ passwords.

Let us build a password with $4$ characters. For the first character there are 36 possible options. You pick some character and you are left with 35. For the second character, you have 35 options, so there are $36\times35$ ways of building a password with 2 characters. You still have 34 characters left so there are $36\times35\times34$ unique passwords with 3 characters, and with no repeated characters. Since 33 characters are left, we pick the last one and get a password with 4 characters. Hence there are $36\times35\times34\times33$ passwords with 4 characters.

Repeating for 5 and 6 characters we get a total of $36\times35\times34\times33\times32$ *5-character* passwords and $36\times35\times34\times33\times32\times31$ *6-character* passwords.

We add the totals up to $36\times35\times34\times33\times32\times31 + 36\times35\times34\times33\times32 + 36\times35\times34\times33 = \frac{36!}{30!} + \frac{36!}{31!} + \frac{36!}{32!}$

Now on to the second question. How many passwords contain *only* the letters of his name? Since all letters in his name are unique and his name has 6 letters, then such a password can only be a *permutation* of his name. There are $n!$ permutations of $n$ unique objects.

Since you are talking about probability, it should be

$$P(password\ with\ letters\ in\ justin) = \frac{passwords\ that\ satisfy\ your\ criteria}{total\ number\ of\ passwords}$$

Hence the probability is

$$\frac{6!}{\frac{36!}{30!} + \frac{36!}{31!} + \frac{36!}{32!}}$$

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is very helpful.